# Is it possible to create a function in SQL server to act as clause e.g. Where or Limit

Tags: sql-server, functions

I've found a simple way to mimic the limit clause is SQL server by using

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
OFFSET 22
ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

I'd like to replace those two line with

```
LIMIT(22, 5)
e.g.

SELECT * FROM customers
LIMIT(22, 5)
```

Comment: Without ORDER BY your apparent order is an illusion which can disappear at any time.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Basically, no. If you have optimized your design and code in every other way imaginable and this is where you think saving a few keystrokes will change your life, take a day off and go outside in the sun. :-)

Comment: AaronBertrand I was just trying to not have to remember one more database platform specific set of SQL commands to achive something in multiple databases that we interact with at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no macros in T-SQL to make that syntax look simpler (and non-standard!) or to perform inline substitution, at least in a native non-dynamic query. You do know that you can parameterize it, though, right?

```
ORDER BY <need an ORDER BY>
  OFFSET ((@PageNumber-1)*@PageSize) ROWS 
  FETCH NEXT (@PageSize) ROWS ONLY;
```

This way you are always adding the `OFFSET` clause but you can do it in a very standard way and not really have to look at it during everyday coding.

I suppose you could do what you want if you're okay with building your query using dynamic SQL, for example you could create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Limit(@pn VARCHAR(12), @ps VARCHAR(12))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (N' OFFSET ' + @pn + ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + @ps + ' ROWS ONLY');
END
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... ORDER BY ...' + dbo.Limit(22,5);

PRINT @sql;
```

This looks kind of like what you typed in your sample, but I don't think it's what you really meant (or should want), unless you already have other reasons (e.g. wildly varying order by parameters or search filters) to use dynamic SQL anyway... still, this obfuscation and simplification doesn't help anybody learn SQL Server-specific syntax, and makes it harder for those people to write this stuff when they *can't* use the function. I don't think this is the type of "optimization" you should be spending a whole lot of effort on. You type these queries once, and when someone does learn the actual syntax, it is hard to justify using "shortcuts" that might not be any easier to remember in the long run (and can be harder to maintain if, for example, they need to made more flexible later).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems like there isn't a correct way to accomplish what I'm looking for. From what you said it seems better to use correct T-SQL and others in our team at work are better off learning the specific SQL for each database platform they have to interact with, which I guess makes sense it's better to know how things work than to mask them with sort cuts.